# Kaggle API Token Not Downloading

Tags: kaggle

I am unable to download "Kaggle.JSON" to use the Kaggle API. I have not come across anyone else online with this problem. I have tried on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari browsers and on Windows as well as Mac OS. Every time I click on "Create new API token," no downloads are triggered. Is there an alternate way to get this file? I receive the "Ensure kaggle.json is in the location ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json to use the API." message but nothing is downloaded. I do not receive a prompt to save as and the file is not saved in any location. Is there any advice as to why this is not working?

[Kaggle API option in Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V98k2.png)

Comment: Pop open your browser's dev tools and see what's going on.

Comment: I was able to find a "token" that I'm assuming has my authentication key but otherwise I am not sure what I am looking for to fix this specific issue

Comment: if you found your token, what's your issue?

Answer (score -1):

Disable the pop-up blocker. Or try another browser

Answer (score -1):

Interstingly, when you click the `Create Token` button its not a link but a json file URL encoded.

If you see that download is failed, just go to the downloads page of your browser and look for the url, My one is here:

[image]

Copy the link or open in a new tab and you see the Json file.:
[image]

Save this data as kaggle.json file. Then move it to .kaggle folder in C drive. Enjoy, Happy Coding!!